# different scores when using scikit-learn pipeline vs. doing it manually

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

Simple example below using minmaxscaler, polyl features and linear regression classifier.

## doing via pipeline:

```
pipeLine = make_pipeline(MinMaxScaler(),PolynomialFeatures(), LinearRegression())

pipeLine.fit(X_train,Y_train)
print(pipeLine.score(X_test,Y_test))
print(pipeLine.steps[2][1].intercept_)
print(pipeLine.steps[2][1].coef_)

0.4433729905419167
3.4067909278765605
[ 0.         -7.60868833  5.87162697]
```

## doing manually:

```
X_trainScaled = MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(X_train)
X_trainScaledandPoly = PolynomialFeatures().fit_transform(X_trainScaled)

X_testScaled = MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(X_test)
X_testScaledandPoly = PolynomialFeatures().fit_transform(X_testScaled)

reg = LinearRegression()
reg.fit(X_trainScaledandPoly,Y_train)
print(reg.score(X_testScaledandPoly,Y_test))
print(reg.intercept_)
print(reg.coef_)
print(reg.intercept_ == pipeLine.steps[2][1].intercept_)
print(reg.coef_ == pipeLine.steps[2][1].coef_)

0.44099256691782807
3.4067909278765605
[ 0.         -7.60868833  5.87162697]
True
[ True  True  True]
```

Comment: Is is possible that `X_test` and `X_train` have different min/max values? Can you try it with a defined dataset and add it to your question?

Comment: You are not supposed to `fit_transform` twice. You are supposed to `fit` using the training data and then ONLY call `transform` for the test data.

Comment: Thanks guys :) I can see the error of my ways now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in your manual steps, where you do the refitting of the Scaler using test data, you need to fit it on train data and use fitted instance on test data, see here for details: [How to normalize the Train and Test data using MinMaxScaler sklearn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50565937/how-to-normalize-the-train-and-test-data-using-minmaxscaler-sklearn) and [StandardScaler before and after splitting data](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/38395/standardscaler-before-and-after-splitting-data)

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification, make_regression
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

X, y = make_regression(n_features=3, n_samples=50, n_informative=1, noise=1)
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

pipeLine = make_pipeline(MinMaxScaler(),PolynomialFeatures(), LinearRegression())

pipeLine.fit(X_train,Y_train)
print(pipeLine.score(X_test,Y_test))
print(pipeLine.steps[2][1].intercept_)
print(pipeLine.steps[2][1].coef_)

scaler = MinMaxScaler().fit(X_train)
X_trainScaled = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_trainScaledandPoly = PolynomialFeatures().fit_transform(X_trainScaled)


X_testScaled = scaler.transform(X_test)
X_testScaledandPoly = PolynomialFeatures().fit_transform(X_testScaled)

reg = LinearRegression()
reg.fit(X_trainScaledandPoly,Y_train)
print(reg.score(X_testScaledandPoly,Y_test))
print(reg.intercept_)
print(reg.coef_)
print(reg.intercept_ == pipeLine.steps[2][1].intercept_)
print(reg.coef_ == pipeLine.steps[2][1].coef_)
```